# Solving the equation $\ln(x)=-x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, special-functions, transcendental-equations

I tried solving this equation for a long time but did not succeed. Any help is appreciated.

$$\ln x=-x$$

I am not sure the tag is correct, I am not familiar with English mathematical terms. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: what should it be?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is $xe^x=1$, which means the solution is to use [Lambert's W-function.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

In this case, it is $W(1)$. This is also called the [Omega constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omega_constant).

Comment: And that's the $A$ and $\Omega$ of it!

Answer (score 4):

To add to Thomas' answer, here are the steps
$$ \ln x = -x $$
$$ e^{\ln x} = e^{-x} $$
$$ x = \frac{1}{e^{x}} $$
$$ xe^x = 1 $$
$$ x = W(1) $$
Where, $W$ is the [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).