# How to solve $2x-e^{-x}=0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am wondering how to solve the equation $2x-e^{-x}=0$?

I tried:

$2x=e^{-x}\implies\log(2x)=-x$
$\implies\log2+\log x=-x\implies\log2=-x-\log x$

Then I am stuck.

Is there any elementary way to solve the equation?

Thanks.

Comment: Elementary? No. Same as $xe^x=\frac{1}{2}$, so $x=W(\frac{1}{2})$ where $W$ is Lambert W.

Comment: You could use the Lambert W function (which in my opinion is a very cheap way of solving it), or solve it numerically

Comment: I think ,you can turn the equation into two simple function $e^{-x}=f(x)$ ,$2x=g(x)$ ...then plot them together . cross section is solution

Comment: similar questions: [Solving the equation $\ln(x)=-x$](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1080151/11206),  [Solve $\exp(x)(5-x)=5$ by hand](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1333976/11206), [Solving $4x = e^x$ without graphing and looking for intersection](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1699104/11206)

Answer (score 5):

$$
2x - e^{-x} = 0 \iff \\
2x\,e^x -1 = 0 \iff \\
x \, e^x = 1/2 \iff \\
x = W(1/2) = 0.3517337\dotsb
$$
where $W$ is the inverse to $f(x) = x e^x$. This is known as Lambert W function and is a special function, not an elementary one.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This is what I mean.$$2x=g(x)\\f(x)=e^{-x}$$plot both of them .the cross section point is solution of equation. 
  we can approximate it by numerical methods .

Answer (score 0):

Tou can't get result in closed form, but there are some easy possibilities to calculate it:

1. To [calc](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=W(1%2F2)) W(1/2) with Wolfram Alpha
2. To use series from [the article](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html)
3. To use [iterative method](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19BCqc5ieN030LkeqC9pAqOm5RDVhOq3O_fqS8jqwLyg/edit#gid=0)
   $$x_{i+1}=\dfrac{\exp(-x_i)+x_i}3$$
   with $x_0=0.$

Answer (score 0):

If you do not (or cannot) use Lambert function, numerical mathods should be used.

Probably the simplest could be Newton method which, starting from a guess $x_0$, will update it according to $$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$ For the case where $$f(x)=2x-e^{-x}\implies f'(x)=2+e^{-x}\implies x_{n+1}=\frac{x_n+1}{2 e^{x_n}+1}$$ Being lazy, let us start using $x_0=0$. Then the sucessive iterates will be $$x_1=0.3333333333$$ $$x_2=0.3516893316$$ $$x_3=0.3517337110$$ $$x_4=0.3517337112$$ which is the solution for ten significant figures.